# Добрый день,Я новичок нужна помощь с путем питона к файлу(убунту не находит файл питона)

Tags: python

друзья написал код маленького калькулятора на sublime.text, сохранил файл под названием calculator.py в папке Python, после чего вызываю терминал в нем пытаюсь вызвать сохраненный файл и тут мне выводит вот такое с низу

```
python3: can't open file 'calculator.py': 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Заранее, спасибо всем кто откликнется

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: на редакторе sublime text написал код калькулятора  файл сохранил в папке под названием  'calculator.py'  после чего пытаюсь запустить его в терминале,а в ответ 'nosuch file or directory'

Comment: Добавьте больше деталей. Как вы запускаете ваш скрипт и т.д.

Comment: проверьте с помощью команды `ls` в терминале, какие есть файлы и директории, вам просто необходимо указать конечный путь к скрипту python

Comment: проверил с помощью ls папка где сохранен файл calculator.py там есть в наличии

Comment: а как указать конечный путь к скрипту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы запустить `calculator.py` надо сначала в терминале провалиться в эту папку, например:

```
cd /root/Python
```

Затем командой `ls` проверь находится ли `calculator.py` в этой папке, если да, то запускай скрипт

```
python3 calculator.py
```

Есть и более простой способ. Открой папку **Python** и правой кнопкой мыши выбери `Open Terminal Here`. Терминал откроется в нужной папке, можешь запускать скрипт.

Как указать конечный путь: открой необходимую папку и вверху нажми на карандаш или по адресной строке. Это и будет конечным путем.

Comment: Спасибо что откликнулись ,скажите пожалуйста у меня установлен Ubuntu ,тут все немного по другому ,данная последовательность cd/rood/Python тоже актуальна ?

Comment: Эта последовательность была указана как пример. Где была создана папка Python? Если папка создана была на рабочем столе, то путь в терминале будет другой. Я написал в ответе как посмотреть конечный путь до файла. Откройте папку и вверху посмотрите путь.

Comment: Спасибо ,все получилось:)